# Minimizer of a quadric program in the SPD case

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be SPD. I want to show that the function
$$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx$$ 
fulfills $\nabla\Phi(x)=Ax-b$.

My attempt:

First, we consider a pertubation of $\Phi(x)$ denoted by $\Phi(x+\delta x)$. Then I approximate with a Taylor polynomial up to linear order in $\delta x\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\Phi(x+\delta x) - \Phi(x)=\nabla \Phi \delta x + \mathcal{O}(\| (\delta x)^2\|)$$

Now I just use the definition of $\Phi$ and insert:

$\frac{1}{2} (x+\delta x)^T A(x+\delta x) - b^T(x+\delta x)- \frac{1}{2} x^TAx+ b^T x=\nabla\Phi(x)\delta x$

Solving and ditching the $\frac{1}{2}(\delta x)^T A\delta x$ term I get

$\frac{1}{2}x^tA\delta x + \frac{1}{2}(\delta x)^tAx - b^T\delta x = \nabla \Phi(x)\delta x$

Then I use that $AB=(B^TA^T)^T$ for two matrices and obtain

$\left ( (Ax)^T - b^T\right ) \delta x = \nabla\Phi(x)\delta x$

or equivalently

$\left ( Ax -b -\nabla \Phi(x) \right )^T\delta x=0 $

How can I conclude from this that $\nabla \Phi(x)=Ax-b$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have misunderstood the definition of $\nabla \Phi$.  By definition, $\nabla \Phi(x)$ is the (unique) matrix $M$ such that for all perturbations $\delta x$, we have
$$
\Phi(x + \delta x) - \Phi(x) = M^T \delta x + o(\|\delta x\|).
$$
You have already shown (up to some rearragement of your steps) that
$$
\Phi(x + \delta x) - \Phi(x) = (Ax - b)^T \delta x + o(\|\delta x\|).
$$
It follows that $\nabla \Phi = Ax-b$.

Comment: I understand, you just use the definition of the derivative there. But can you also conclude without this, using my proof?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta I'm not sure what "conclude without this" really means in this context; how are you supposed to say that something is a derivative without using the definition of a derivative in some way?  To address the particular step that you ended on, it is indeed true that if matrices $M_1,M_2$ satisfy $M_1 \delta x = M_2 \delta x$ for all vectors $\delta x$, then $M_1 = M_2$.  So, we indeed have
$$
\left ( (Ax)^T - b^T\right ) \delta x = [\nabla\Phi(x)]^T\delta x \  \text{for all }\delta x \implies
\nabla \Phi = Ax - b.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to know! I know its artificial, but I wanted to try it.